# Control RGB colors on PC using Java

Tags: java, gpu, cpu, rgb, motherboard

**I plan to make a Java application that controls RGB on my PC**, such as on the CPU Fans, GPU, CPU Cooler, Motherboard, etc. *Is it possible also to control USB components like the keyboard and mouse RGB?*

**How can I achieve that?** I was searching but didn't find good results.

Comment: you would need to communicate to the hardware directly, maybe using some c code in JNI might be worth  a try

Comment: Any particular reason for Java?

Comment: No, I just like using Java, but I know also C#.